# Irreducibilty Cyclotomic polynomial $f(x^{n})$

Tags: cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $p$ be a prime.

Let $f(x)=x^{p-1} + x^{p-2}+...+1$.

Let $g(x)$ = $f(x^{n})$ where n is any positive integer.

I know $f(x)$ is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion.

Now i want to show $g(x)$ is irreducible:

If $g(x) = h(x)\cdot k(x) $,

Then $h(x) = (x^{n})^{k} + (x^{n})^{k-1} +....+1$,

And $k(x) = (x^{n})^{l} + (x^{n})^{l-1} +...+ 1$.

If any terms of $k(x)$ or$ h(x)$ is not of the form of $(x^{n})^{m}$ then when multiplied with 1 produces terms which is not in $ g(x).$
Then we can substitute $ x^{n}$ as $ y $
Which will produce that cyclotomic polynomial $ f(x)$ is reducible.

Which is a contradiction

Is my proof correct?

Comment: The last night should read reducible, not irreducible and you should state that this is a contradiction.

Comment: @cyclotomicfield what i did is correct right? Or did I miss something?

Comment: $x^6+1$ is not irreducible @CyclotomicField

Comment: @reuns you are correct can you tell me right generalized result as i saw in a question that if $f(x)$ as the way i have defined then $g(x)= f((x^{t})^{n})$ where $t$ is a prime the it's irreducible

Comment: Do you know where to find that result?

Answer (score 2):

If $p |n$ then $\Phi_n(x^{p^k})$ is irreducible. This is because $\zeta_{np^k}$ is a root of $\Phi_n(x^{p^k})$ ie. $\Phi_{np^k}|\Phi_n(x^{p^k})$, and we know that $\deg \Phi_{np^k} = \varphi(np^k)=p^k \varphi(n)=\deg(\Phi_n(x^{p^k}))$

If $p\nmid n$ then $\deg \Phi_{np^k} = \varphi(np^k)=(p-1)p^{k-1} \varphi(n)$ so
$\Phi_n(x^{p^k})$ isn't irreducible. Example $\Phi_2(x^3)=x^6+1$.

For the same reason $\Phi_n(x^m)$ is irreducible iff $\varphi(nm)=m\varphi(n)$ iff each prime divisor of $m$ divides $n$.

Comment: I'm totally new to this looks like i have a lot of reading to do. Anyway thanks.

Comment: I added a few more hints. The theorem we need  is that the $N$-th cyclotomic polynomial is irreducible and has degree $\varphi(N)$.

Comment: Thank you i understood everything :)